# How to center text TextBlock in DataTemplate of ListView?

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I only have ListView on the Page.

I want TextBlock to be centered horizontaly.

I tried to set Horizonltal alignment of TextBlock to Stretch
or wrap it on StackPanel and set it there without success.

```
<ListView x:Name ="groupList"
              Background="#72AAFF"
              SelectionChanged="groupList_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>          
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"                                
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           FontSize="36"
                           Margin="10,10,0,0"
                           Foreground="#92ECFD"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                               
                           TextAlignment="Center"/>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.Items>
        <x:String>One</x:String>
        <x:String>Two</x:String>
        <x:String>Three</x:String>
        <x:String>etc</x:String>
        <x:String>One</x:String>
        <x:String>One</x:String>
    </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your alignment settings in *TextBlock* won't have effect unless you change the *HorizontalContentAlignment* of container. Add this to container's style and everything should work:

```xml
<ListView x:Name ="groupList" Background="#72AAFF">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <!-- reso of the code -->
```

You can also find some information here [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb961985(v=vs.110).aspx).